# How precise do i have to align timing on a z16xep engine

Tags: timing-belt

I have an z16xep engine, from opel astra h 1.6 gasoline. I removed the timing belt and checked the timing marks. Then I put on the new timing belt about three times. Every time the marking on the lower sprocket does not exactly match. I do not have the special tools. I can manually rotate the timing belt with my hand using the lower sprocket bolt and a tool.

At the moment the timing marks of the top sprockets look like (seems correct):

[image]
The marking below:

[image]

Is this good enough, I can't seem to get it better. I don't know what to do, I am afraid of ruining the engine.

When I watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_ffXzzs02s it seems to be possible to get all markings correct, does anyone have advice?

The top of the markings without hand in the picture:
[image]

Comment: What do the upper marks look like when you align the crank mark correctly, need an image of that (no hand in image please) . Use paint to mark the upper timing marks also.

Comment: I will make a better photo without hand, I have to drive to the car, I hope to be able to provide the image within a few hours.

Comment: I have added the image in the post (see above).

Comment: That is the best it is going to get, they don't always align perfectly, and if your a whole tooth off its obvious. Turn the engine over a few times by the crank bolt and see if they line up any better.

Comment: Before you start the car, ensure you turn the engine over 720° (two complete revolutions) and recheck your timing marks. It's easiest to do this without the spark plugs in, but can be done with them in. Once you've gone through this cycle, recheck your timing marks to make sure they are still aligned, either as they are shown in the image, or with a little luck, they might even line up correctly.

Comment: Further to the above comments; if you can rotate the engine by hand with the tool a few times, without anything clashing, you're good to start the car. The biggest danger with interference engines is a valve being in the cylinder when the piston wants to be there; if you can rotate by hand, you know that's not the case, as you'd notice it (the crank would jam). If you're a tooth off, the engine will run, but not well. However - your marks all look good to me.

Comment: Next time, remove the spark plugs, then you can stop the crankshaft exactly where you want it (bottom pulley aligned EXACTLY to the mark, then check the top.

Answer (score 1):

If those photos were taken at the same time, it looks to me like the right hand cam is one tooth out.

If you were to align the bottom pulley correctly, then the right hand cam marking will move down and the left one will move up.  It looks like the next tooth on the right pulley will then line up with the marking on the left pulley.

Comment: Hard to tell with that angled shot of it but I think your right. I always use a mirror to look straight on at the marks, which is critical.